# Function returning a dictionary with string lengths (keys) and number of occurrence (values) from a list

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of strings and returns a dictionary where the keys represent a length and the values represent how many strings have that length in the list. This is what I have written and my output:

```
def length_counts(stringList):
    stringDict = {}
    for value in stringList:
        stringDict[len(value)] = stringList.count(value)
    return stringDict

#test
sa_countries = ["Brazil", "Venezuela", "Argentina", "Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Peru"]
print(length_counts(sa_countries))
```

Output:

```
{6: 1, 9: 1, 7: 1, 4: 1}
```

Correct output should be:

```
{6: 1, 9: 2, 7: 2, 4: 1}
```

Which says there is 1 string with 6 letters, 2 strings with 9 letters, 2 strings with 7 letters, and 1 string with 4 letters.

Comment: Think about your logic more carefully; what happens for Argentina, for example? Add some prints or otherwise debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

count will give you the number of occurences of that particular element. So the count of Venezuela will give you the number of Venezuela in the list, not the number of 9 letter words. Try something like this.

```
sa_countries = ["Brazil", "Venezuela", "Argentina", "Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Peru"]

dict = {}
for country in sa_countries:
    if (len(country) in dict):
        dict[len(country)] += 1
    else:
        dict[len(country)] = 1

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to accumulate string length counts.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def length_counts(countries):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for country in countries:
        result[len(country)] += 1
    return result
```

Example

```
>>> length_counts(sa_countries)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {6: 1, 9: 2, 7: 2, 4: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting your values.

First you do you `stringList.count('Venezuela')` which is 1. Then you do `stringList.count('Argentina')` which is also 1. So you get value `1` for they key of `9`, twice.

What I would do is first convert the initial list into a list containing the lengths.

```
sa_countries = ["Brazil", "Venezuela", "Argentina", "Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Peru"]
sa_countries_lens = [len(s) for s in sa_countries]
```

That is `[6, 9, 9, 7, 7, 4]`.
Now I would do a count:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(sa_countries_lens)
```

The result is

```
Counter({6: 1, 9: 2, 7: 2, 4: 1})
```

Counter is basically a dict and you can do a dict with an increment and a key check, but Counter is nicer, part of the standard library and pretty widespread.

Comment: Thank you @Azamat Galimzhanov

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); counting is what `Counter` is for:

```
from collections import Counter

sa_countries = ["Brazil", "Venezuela", "Argentina", "Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Peru"]
result = Counter(map(len, sa_countries))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({9: 2, 7: 2, 6: 1, 4: 1})
```

From the documentation:

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a
>   collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their
>   counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any
>   integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is
>   similar to bags or multisets in other languages.